# Strings.xml does not recognise chinese characters

Tags: android, xml, string, localization, chinese-locale

```
public void displayDecDeg(){

        DecimalFormat latlongF = new DecimalFormat("0.00000"); 
        latTV.setText(R.string.latitude + latlongF.format(lat));
        longTV.setText(R.string.longitude + latlongF.format(longi));

    }
```

In the localized version of the Strings.xml file, there is chinese text, but it shows up as numbers while testing.

However, when the chinese characters are hardcoded in place of R.string.longitude, it shows up fine.

```
<string name="latitude">纬度: </string>
<string name="longitude">经度:</string><string name="decDeg">十进制度</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just figured out the solution for my friend. Use `getResources().getString(R.string.latitude)` instead of R.string.latitude.